# Bitcoin RPC returning 401

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I am using `node-bitcoin-rpc` to do some api calls to bitcoind, but I am getting 401 error. I know this simply means unauthorized, but I have no authorization enable in my config file.

Howerver I can query bitcoin client using `vitcoin-cli --regtest listaccounts`, I get the results.

My bitcoin.conf file is pretty simple

```
rpcport=8332
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
regtest=1
debug=rpc
```

PS: I didn't have any bitcoin.conf initially, so I create above one inside .bitcoin folder in home directory.

Answer (score 1):

The RPC interface is an authenticated interface. You need to provide a username and password in order to send RPC commands. These are usually specified in the bitcoin.conf file with the `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` options or the `rpcauth` option. There are also temporary RPC credentials stored in the `.cookie` file that can be found in the datadir.

The reason that you have no problems with `bitcoin-cli` is because it looks up the RPC credentials from the bitcoin.conf file or the `.cookie` file..

Comment: should bitcoin core accept authentication if I manually set `bitcoind.rpcuser="__cookie__"` and `bitcoind.rpcpass=<value from .cookie file>` ?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling a lot as well till recognise the right configuration naming

bitcoin.conf

```
rpcuser=
rpcpassword=
```

lnd.conf

```
bitcoind.rpcuser=
bitcoind.rpcpass=
```