# 401 Unauthorized when try to connect to bitcoin-core using curl

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

The problem: I try to run a `curl` request but get 401 Unauthorized error.

```
curl --user testuser --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "getrawtransaction", "params": ["e0cee...47ac5", true]}' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/ -D -

Enter host password for user 'testuser':
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="jsonrpc"
Date: Sat, 02 Sep 2023 18:12:46 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

The messages in the debug log of the daemon:

```
2023-09-02T15:59:44Z ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:36472
```

I run `bitcoind` this way:

```
/mnt/bitcoin/bin/bitcoind -conf=/mnt/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

Also, I have a symlink for this config:

```
ll ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 25 Sep  1 18:42 /home/user/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf -> /mnt/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

Config:

```
grep -v "#" /mnt/bitcoin/bitcoin.conf | grep -v "^$"                                                                daemon=1
daemonwait=1
...
rest=1
rpcallowip=192.168.0.128/25
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcauth=testuser:3ad8c2e058a161304a911bcc60c208d2$a364136d41edda037d267e909f9f0355537aefee08b6fd29da2eee59559cf084
server=1
[main]
[test]
[signet]
[regtest]
```

`rpcauth` was created this way, and then inserted in the config:

```
python3 bitcoin/share/rpcauth/rpcauth.py testuser testpasst                                                                                            String to be appended to bitcoin.conf:
rpcauth=testuser:3ad8c2e058a161304a911bcc60c208d2$a364136d41edda037d267e909f9f0355537aefee08b6fd29da2eee59559cf084
Your password:
testpasst
```

Also, I tried to replace `rpcauth` with

```
rpcuser=testuser
rpcpassword=testpasst
```

And did

```
kill -HUP `cat /mnt/btc_data/bitcoind.pid`
```

after every config change (idk wether it's needed or not)

Yes, I have "t" at the end of pass everywhere (I'm too frustrated to re-do all this solely to remove the typo, but the password was copy-pasted many times so I 100% sure there's no mis-type answering curl)

I tried: [one](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/115668/401-unauthorized-connection-using-python-bitcoinrpc) [two](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/106395/bitcoinrpc-authproxy-jsonrpcexception-342-non-json-http-response-with-401-u) [three](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36433/bitcoin-rpc-works-in-bitcoin-cli-but-not-in-python-bitcoinrpc-no-json-object) [four](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/77214/bitcoin-rpc-returning-401)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how it sounds, but it works now, without any intervention from my side

The only idea I can think of is that the daemon reloads config not immediately but after some time (I did not try full restart after each config change)

Comment: It does not reload config at all; you need to restart to make new configuration active.

Comment: @PieterWuille is there any command to force config reload without restarting?

Comment: No, there is not.